# Large sample limit of linear and ridge regression

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, linear-model, ridge-regression

I wanted to check if these reasonings are correct.

The formula for a multilinear regression, input $X_{s,i}$, where $s$ is the sample and $i$ the features, and output $Y$, is given by:

$$\beta=(X^+X)^{-1}X^+Y$$

Now if we define:

$Q_{ij}=\sum_s X_{si}X_{sj}, M_j=\sum_s X_{js}Y_s$

than the equation is equivalent to:

$$\beta_i=\sum_{j} [Q^{-1}]_{ij}M_{j}$$

Now we can add the number of samples into this formula $N_s$:

$$\beta_i=\sum_{j} [Q/N_s]^{-1}_{ij}[M/N_s]_{j}$$

and observe that we have some sample averages:

$Q_{ij}/N_s=\sum_s \left( X_{si}X_{sj}\right) /N_s  \rightarrow E[X_iX_j]$

and:

$M_j/N_s=\sum_s \left( X_{js}Y_s \right)/N_s \rightarrow E[X_jY]$,

so that in the large sample limit we expect:

$$\beta_i \rightarrow (E[X_*X_*])_{i,j}^{-1}E[X_jY]$$

- Question 1. Is this result expected/trivial/correct ?

Now we can try to get a large sample limit for Ridge regression. Looking at internet this implies that $Q$ must be replaced with $Q+\lambda I$ and the formula becomes, after inserting as before the number of samples:

$$\beta^R_i=\sum_{j} [(Q+\lambda I)/N_s]^{-1}_{ij}[M/N_s]_{j}$$

But here it looks that as before:

$(Q+\lambda I)/N_s \rightarrow Q/N_s \rightarrow E[X_iX_j]$

because the added factor becomes negligible. If we want to have a different limit we should have $\lambda$ scaling with the samples : $\lambda=\rho N_s$ and in this case:

$(Q+\rho N_s I)/N_s \rightarrow Q/N_s \rightarrow E[X_iX_j]+\rho I$

, so that:

$$ \beta^R_i \rightarrow (E[X_*X_*]+\rho I)_{i,j}^{-1}E[X_jY] $$

- Question 2. Is this result expected/trivial/correct ?
- Question 3. If yes, is it correct that the ridge regression factor should scale with $N_s$ to get a finite value ?
- Question 4. Can we understand something about the behavior of Ridge regression looking at the large sample limit formulas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, yes.

1. Indeed, consistency of OLS for linear projection coefficients is basically an application of the law of large numbers.
2. Indeed - ridge is a tool to trade off some bias against less variance in small samples. When sample size goes to infinity, that tradeoff vanishes when the number of parameters stays constant.
3. Technically, yes, although - see 2) - I would not see why one would want a different limit.
4. Probably - e.g., again see 2): the ridge adjustment only matters in finite samples.

Comment: Thanks I think I had the math right but not the interpretation... +1 I will take some time to think about your answer and if I do not have further questions accept...

Comment: Thanks for your insights. I have the impression that this effect may be also clear if we consider a derivation of Ridge regression as maximizing a posterior that one gets putting a prior on the linear weights. Independently of the prior with infinite data one should recover the correct values. The regularization should serve in this sense to speed up convergence with the number of samples.

Comment: This kind of bias is a bit different instead than model bias, that instead survives in the infinite sample limit.

Comment: I just added what where my thoughts/understanding reading your answer. If you have some comment let me know but in any case I accept the answer and thank you again.

Comment: Yes, I agree with your view and perspective that the data will dominate regular priors in large samples and that this is therefore a finite sample effect, unlike inconsistency resulting from e.g. omitted variables which does not wash out with more data - comparing many apples with many oranges does not make the comparison any better...